# Size of the maximum matching in arbitrary graph

Tags: randomized-algorithms, matching, minimum-cuts

I am asked to find a probabilistic algorithm to determine the size of the maximum matching of an arbitrary simple undirected graph $ G $.

My claim is that, it is equivalent to find a global min cut on $ G $ (where each edge had capacity 1). To find that, I can output all $n \choose 2$ min cuts, determine the longest and that is indeed my size of a maximum matching. And to be probabilistic, finding min cut could be done with [Karger's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karger%27s_algorithm).

I was very confused that no reference source I found was relaring size of max matching to size of min cut, which doubt me a lot if i am in the correct direction. I only read bipartite versions, which seems unapplicable here.

Question is, for arbitrary $G$, how should I probabilistically find the size of the maximum matching?

Comment: Where did you get this problem? In which class? Are you familiar with Schwartz–Zippel?

Comment: Currently, this looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), in that you really want to find a maximum matching, but what you ask for is the relationship between a minimum cut and a maximum matching.  Which of the two problems are you really trying to solve?

Comment: I see. I am reformulating the question now.